# Not able connect with mfp 7.1 while adding wlapp file manually

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with ionic project using mfp 7.1. I have added the .wlapp file manually into mfp console. After that, I have tried to connect with mfp 7.1
using the following code,

```
WL.Client.connect({
     onSuccess :function(){
       alert("success");
     },
     onFailure :function(error){
       alert("Fail"+JSON.stringify(error));
     },
 });
```

**I am getting failure, "404" error as "Service not found".**

My requirement is, I have to add wlapp file manually without using "mfp push".

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The "404" is the clue. This means the client application cannot reach the server. Check your client application's wlclient.properties or worklight.plist file to verify your MFP server's hostname and port. 
Correct it, rebuild and relaunch the application.